# How can I get a MP3 file info for my musicplayer in android developed with C#

Tags: c#, android, title

I develop a little musicplayer using Android.media, I want to get the title, artist and etc. of the song, I search all over the internet but I don't find a code in C# !!! :/ plz help!!!

Comment: You use this? http://xamarin.com/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
     * SD CARD QUERIES
     */
    public ArrayList<Track> getAllSdCardTracks(Context context) {
        ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();

            Cursor c = context
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID }, "1=1",
                            null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String mArtist = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    String mTitle = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String mId = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                    String mAlbumName = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                    String mAlbumID = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                    String mPath = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                    long mDuration = c
                            .getLong(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                    String mFormattedDuration = DateUtils
                            .formatElapsedTime(mDuration / 1000);
                    Track track = new Track(mAlbumID, mAlbumName, mArtist, mId, mTitle, mPath   , mFormattedDuration);
                    tracks.add(track);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
                if (c != null)
                    c.close();
            }

        return tracks;

    }


public class Track{
String mAlbumId;
String mAlbumName;
String mArtist
String mId;
String mTitle;
String mPath;
String mDuration

public Track(String albumID,String albumName,String artist,String id,String title,String path ,String formattedDuration)
{
this.mAlbumId = albumId;
this.mAlbumName = albumName;
this.mArtist = artist;
this.mId = id;
this.mTitle = title;
this.mPath = path;
this.mDuration = formattedDuration;
}
}
```

Comment: tnx a lot, but it not recognize ArrayList<Track> and other functions, there are in wich class?!

Comment: Track is just a container class to contain data, i didn't add it because you might not need all other data

Comment: Try reading this http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/part_2_-_using_the_contacts_contentprovier/ `Cursor` is an Android class.. Sounds like you should declare it with the interface ICursor and then get it `var loader = new CursorLoader(activity, uri, projection, null, null, null);
   var cursor = (ICursor)loader.LoadInBackground();`